# Rails 6 - Shared object "libruby.so.27" LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've compiled my app without any issues but it doesn't work. In the logs I've following error:

```
Error: The application encountered the following error: Shared object "libruby.so.27" not found, required by "strscan.so" - /usr/home/onyxlab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/strscan-3.0.1/lib/strscan.so (LoadError)
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Rails is interpreted not compiled so not sure what you mean by "Compiled my app without any issues"? Please explain when this error occurs and post the full stack trace so we can interpret what is happening. There is not enough info to answer you. Also post any code that might be using libruby

Comment: I was deploying my app through phusion passenger, I've compiled rails assets and run database migrations. Everything's was fine but when I tried to access my website following error showed:
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.
And in my log there was error what I posted above

Comment: Now I realized that my current Ruby version is 2.6.3 but here
'Error: The application encountered the following error: Shared object "libruby.so.27" not found, required by "strscan.so" - /usr/home/onyxlab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/strscan-3.0.1/lib/strscan.so (LoadError)'
Version is 2.7.2

Comment: Much more info is needed as already requested, there is no way this is solveable with so little info. Would love to help more but it it is just not possible. At the barest minimum a full stack trace is needed and the code that the stack trace is pointing to